# Преобразование массива из hash`ей

Tags: ruby, хеширование

Доброго времени суток!
Есть массив из хэшей такого рода:

```
[{:album_id => 1, :stream => 15}, {:album_id => 2, :stream => 10}]
```

и так далее. Каким образом можно преобразовать этот массив,чтобы получить в итоге массив такого вида:

```
[{1 => 15}, {2 => 10}]
```

Очень признателен за помощь.Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такой итератор [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
array = [{:album_id => 1, :stream => 15}, {:album_id => 2, :stream => 10}]
result = array.map { |hash| { hash[:album_id] => hash[:stream] } }
result #=> [{1=>15}, {2=>10}]
```